# The wrong date format in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using luxon library to convert the time:

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;

console.log(DateTime.local('Sun Jan 23 2003 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)').toISODate())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@2.3.1/build/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

I expect to get this format: `2003-04-23`
 Why i get null and how to get the expected format using `luxon`?

Comment: Have a look at this article! you will find the solution https://www.thisdot.co/blog/how-to-handle-time-zones-using-datetime-and-luxon

Comment: Why would you expect `Jan` to become `04`? :) I assume it's a typo..

Comment: @Amadan, sorry it was a typo: `2003-01-23`

Comment: Also — [`DateTime.local`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimelocal) can't parse strings. You want `DateTime.fromFormat`, since this is not one of the formats that Luxon [can parse](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/parsing).

Comment: @Amadan, i tried this   console.log(DateTime.fromFormat("Sun Jan 23 2003 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)", "LLLL dd yyyy")
, but there is an error. Could you help please? It will help me a lot

Comment: You will never be able to parse that string. For one thing, `Jan 23 2003` was a Thursday; even if the format string was absolutely correct, Luxon would reject the date as invalid. How are you getting that string?

Answer (score 1):

You have the date format wrong, Luxon’s format that belongs in `.local` is `year?, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond`

Example:

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;

console.log(
DateTime.local(2003, 1, 23, 17, 36) .toISODate())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@2.3.1/build/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

For your case you can use the code below to get what you are looking for.

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;
const date = new Date("Sun Jan 23 2003 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)")
const dat = DateTime.fromJSDate(date)
console.log(dat.toFormat('MM-dd-yyyy'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@2.3.1/build/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: but how to transform this Sun Jan 23 2003 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time) ?

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to transform it to?

Comment: i need to transform this format Sun Jan 23 2003 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time) into 2003-01-23

Comment: could you help please?

Comment: Yes, I’m looking through the documents right now.

Comment: You can’t use that format at all, is it possible you can use the format Luxon uses?

Comment: Just edited the correct way for you.

Answer (score 0):

can be done with pure date

```js
var date =new Date("Sun Jan 23 2003 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)")
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;
var dat = DateTime.fromJSDate(date)
console.log(dat.toString().split("T")[0])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@2.3.1/build/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
```